# Two two bars controllers in a split view?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

So I have built a custom iPad split view controller and two bar controller side by side. The tab bar controller seem to work as expected except for the second tab bar controller extending the view into and under the tab bar. This effectively cuts out the bottom part of the view and the views in the second tab bar controller reports a height of 50 points greater than the first tab bar controller.
Is there a property on the tab bar controller to set so that it doesn't stretch the view under the tab bar?

Comment: Try `self.myNavigationController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES`

Comment: CodaFi, thanks for the reply. I tried setting the navigationController.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES to the second tab bar controller but that didn't help. Also the views in the second tab bar controller are not embedded in a navigation controller.